# neo4j graph import slower when using transactional end point

Tags: node.js, transactions, neo4j, cypher

I have an application which imports user profile and social data on to a graph. My app importer is a nodejs app. The first pass of my importer used node-neo4j and async cypher queries to import the data. I combined this with the Q promise library to string together thousands of queries.

My second pass was an attempt to use the transactional REST endpoint: /db/data/transaction/commit and a single JSON document containing 5000 transactions.

What I'm seeing is that the the first approach completed in 15 seconds while the second approach (which I expect is thousands of fewer HTTP calls) actually takes 30 seconds to complete. I'm at a loss for how the second approach could be twice as slow.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: Perhaps you can share some code, what your statements look like? and how you executed against that endpoint? Perhaps missing some indexes or constraints?

Comment: I'm essentially doing this: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api-transactional.html#rest-api-begin-and-commit-a-transaction-in-one-request  and I'm not using neo4j-node and instead using the node request module to make a single HTTP RESTFul call.

Comment: Also the actual payload I'm sending include 5000 transactions.

Answer (score 0):

Transactional commits trade memory and ordered operations for performance.

If you're looking for speedy imports, I recommend `LOAD CSV`.